# Accessing webservice with credentials using vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, internet-explorer

I'm working on a longer script for Access and at one point it is necessary to check a webservice for the latest version of a file (the filename). This webservice is only accessible via a browser with an URL like `https://webservice.example.com:1234/Server/test.jsp?parameter=value` then it is necessary to authenticate with the standard browser username password pop up.
Of course I could skip this pop up if I'd use something like `https://user:password@webservice.example.com:1234/Server/test.jsp?parameter=value` instead. (Note that it is not about security at this point the password only exists for the sake of having a password and it's totally acceptable to store it as clear text)

At the moment I already use the following working code to get information from another
 website:

```
Dim appIE As Object
Dim sURL as String, infoStr as String
Set appIE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}") 'class id of InternetExplorerMedium
sURL = "https://webservice.example.com:1234/Server/test.jsp?parameter=value"
With appIE
    .Navigate sURL
    .Visible = False
End With

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

infoStr = appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("body").item.innerText
```

However, if I add the credentials to the URL as I would do in the browser 
`sURL = "https://user:password@webservice.example.com:1234/Server/test.jsp?parameter=value"`
I will get the following error:

> Runtime error '-2146697202 (800c000e)': method 'navigate' of object
>   'IWebBrowser2' failed

Does anybody know why it is failing if I add the credentials or has anybody an idea how to do this differently?

Comment: The _username:password_ option is not supported for [Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) or [Digest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) authentication. Instead, you should specify the authentication header in the headers argument. I can  explain how to do that after you specify the authentication mode expected by the server.

Comment: How can I find out which authentication mode is expected?

Comment: Use your favorite tool to read the response header after making a request. The response code should be 401 Unauthorized, and it should contain a www-authenticate header with the desired authentication mode.

Comment: Thank you. If I got this right it is expecting basic mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your website requires Basic authentication, it's relatively easy to authenticate using a basic authentication header.

We need to be able to Base64 encode content, so first we need to define a helper function for that:

```
Public Function ToBase64(Bytes() As Byte) As String
    Dim XMLElement As Object
    Set XMLElement = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0").createElement("tmp")
    XMLElement.DataType = "bin.base64"
    XMLElement.nodeTypedValue = Bytes
    ToBase64 = Replace(XMLElement.Text, vbLf, "")
End Function
```

Then, a second helper to create a basic authentication header:

```
Public Function CreateBasicAuthHeader(Username As String, Password As String) As String
    'Assuming ASCII encoding, UTF-8 is harder
    CreateBasicAuthHeader = "Authorization: Basic " & ToBase64(StrConv(Username & ":" & Password, vbFromUnicode))
End Function
```

A quick validation shows that `?CreateBasicAuthHeader("Aladdin", "OpenSesame")` returns `Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l`, which is the expected header according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side)

Then, you can use this in the `Navigate` method:

```
Dim appIE As Object
Dim sURL as String, infoStr as String
Set appIE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}") 'class id of InternetExplorerMedium
sURL = "https://webservice.example.com:1234/Server/test.jsp?parameter=value"
With appIE
    .Navigate sURL, Headers:=CreateBasicAuthHeader("MyUsername", "MyPassword")
    .Visible = False
End With

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

infoStr = appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("body").item.innerText
```

This assumes that the server either expects ASCII encoding, or your username and password are both only ASCII characters and the server expects UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Thank you! However, this will leave me with a run time error 448 Named argument not found in line `.Navigate sURL, Headers:=CreateBasicAuthHeader("MyUsername", "MyPassword")`. Seems like `.Navigate` is not accepting the argument `Header`

Comment: @Ruvox It's the 5th argument, so you should also be able to do `.Navigate sURL, , , , CreateBasicAuthHeader("MyUsername", "MyPassword")`. It's HeaderS, not Header, btw.

Comment: Ahhhh, nevermind. Sorry indeed I just wrote `Header` this of course led to my error.